# IMAP port permission (Python)

Tags: linux, email, python, imap

I'm writing a program to read emails from python

when I execute below code it hangs in the last line

```
import imaplib
mail_server = "192.168.2.2"
connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(mail_server,993)
```

I have already opened port 993.

is any other port permissions are required for imap connection to work?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have connected to IMAP you will need login credentials.  There are a variety of formats that could be required depending on the configuration of the IMAP server.  Opening a connection to an IMAP server gives you very little functionality until you have logged in as the desired user.